# Objective C: Turning off music after switching views

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, model-view-controller, avaudioplayer

So my audio is working fine if I stay on the same View Controller, the music turns on and off how I want it to. However, when I modal to another view controller with a different header file and return to my original View Controller, I can no longer turn my music on or off. Here is my code:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
//Play Background Music in .1 second after game loads
    [self performSelector:@selector(playBackgroundMusic) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

-(void) playBackgroundMusic {

        //Music int is used so music doesnt play over itself
        if (musicInt == 0) {

            NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
            resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/JungleMusic.wav"];
            NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
            NSError* err;

            //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
            player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                      [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

            musicInt = musicInt + 1;
            //set our delegate and begin playback
            player.delegate = self;
            [player play];
            player.numberOfLoops = -1;
            player.currentTime = 0;
            player.volume = 1.0;
        }
}

//Used to turn the music on or off
    -(IBAction)musicTest:(id)sender{
        if (player.playing) {
            [player stop];
        } else {
            [player play];
        }
    }
```

I also synthesized my player in the same .m file:

```
@synthesize player;
```

And in my .h file I declare the AVAudioPlayer

```
    @interface ViewController1 : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

    {
        AVAudioPlayer *player;
    }

@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated. I just can't understand why I wouldn't be able to turn my audio on/off after simply modeling to another view controller? Thanks!

Comment: In order to be able to start and stop your music you need to be able to communicate with the view controller that is playing it in the first place. How are your getting from your first, music playing view controller to your second VC, and how are you getting back? Are you presenting the second VC as a modal and then dismissing it? Pushing onto a navigation stack and then popping?

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks for responding. The app is storyboard based and leaves the view controller with a modal and comes back with a modal on the click of a button each time. I am not sure what pushing onto a navigation stack and popping is.

Comment: Coming back with a modal is wrong. You are creating an endless series of modals. When you "go back" with a modal, you're not going back at all. You're creating a new instance of your original VC and putting it on top of the pile of modals. You either need to use an unwind segue or make the back button invoke an IBAction instead of a segue, where the action calls `dismissViewController:animated:completion:

Comment: I changed it up and it works now! Thanks for your help I used [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; for my back button instead and it fixed the issue! @DuncanC

Comment: Please, be polite enough to accept the answer which solved your issue. (-:

Comment: If my answer solved your problem you should click he check mark to accept it. That way others know that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on our conversation in comments, the answer is that you had a segue to go to the second view controller, and a second segue to go back, which actually created a new instance of the original view controller (and you wound up with **three** view controllers.)

The solution is to either connect your back button to an IBAction that invokes `dismissViewController:animated:completion:`, or to connect the back button to an unwind segue. When you do one of those things the back button dismisses the second view controller and exposes the existing first view controller rather than creating a new copy of the second view controller.